# On click action on new DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck on 'on click' action on new DOM elemets in JQuery. I have approximately the following html setup:

```
<ul class="dateList">
    <li>
        <a href='#' data-date="2016-01-01">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#' data-date="2016-01-02">
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="timeList">
    <li>
        <a href='#' data-time="00:00:00">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#' data-time="03:00:00">
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the page loads, the time list is loaded for the first available date. If user clicks on a different date, the current time list items get removed and new items are generated from pre-loaded json.

If the user click on the time, it is supposed to show relevant information. And it does after the page is loaded, however, once the date gets changed and the new time list items are created the on click event stops working on new time items.

I've tried adding $('.timeList').find('li') and $('.timeList li').find('a') to the end of the function that generates the new time list items but it does not seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure "j" tag is correct?

Comment: To keep your code working you can try just to change the li options but to keep the ul. If you replace the entire ul structure you have to use .on (delegated events)

Comment: ul.timelist does not get removed, only the li elements

Answer (score 1):

you will need to reference a higher level selector, such as body which was created prior to the dynamic content addition

something like

```
$('body').on('click','.timeList li',function(){
// do stuff
})
```